# RXJS SwitchMap not working properly with Resolver after Angular Upgrade

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a component where a user chooses a report type to generate.

The component.ts function is like so:

```
generateReport(reportType, projectReport) {
  this.showSpinner = true;
  if(reportType === 'project-weekly-report')
    this.router.navigate(['/weeklyReport', projectReport]).catch<any>(this.handleError.bind(this));
  else this.router.navigate(['/monthlyReport']).catch<any>(this.handleError.bind(this));
}
```

This route it forwards to has a component that uses a resolver to handle the loading of the report. The ngOnInit() of the component looks like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.report = this.route.snapshot.data['projectWeeklyReport'].result;
}
```

The resolver looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectWeeklyReportResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService, private http: HttpClient) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.reportService.getProjectWeeklyReport(route.paramMap.get('projectName'));
  }
}
```

This resolver calls the following function in the service:

```
getProjectWeeklyReport(projectName) {
  var workerUrl = this.reportUrl + '/weeklyreport/projectname/' + projectName + '/job/';
  return this.http
    .get<any>(this.reportUrl + '/weeklyreport/projectname/' + projectName, this.getAuthOptions(true))
    .pipe(
      switchMap(workerId => this.pollFor(workerId, isWorkerCompleted, isWorkerFailed, 2000, workerUrl)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

This method hits the server to tell it to start generating the report. As the report takes some time to generate, this the job has been hived off to a worker job. We then poll this worker job to  check if the report has completed generating the report.

The polling function looks like this:

```
type CustomPollOperator = (data: any, condComp: (d) => boolean, condFail: (d) => boolean, ms: number, url: string) => Observable<any>

const isWorkerCompleted = w => w.result;
const isWorkerFailed = w => w.failedReason;

//Convenience method for polling operation
pollFor: CustomPollOperator = (data, condComp, condFail, ms, url) => {
  let shouldPoll = true;

  return interval(ms)
    .pipe(
      tap(() => console.warn('polling', shouldPoll)),
      takeWhile(() => shouldPoll),
      switchMap(() => this.http.get<any>(url + data.id, this.getAuthOptions(true))),
      tap(res => {
        if(condComp(res)) {
          shouldPoll = false;
        }
        else if(condFail(res)) {
          shouldPoll = false;
          throw new Error('Polling worker job failed');              
        }
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
}
```

Before I updated from angular 9 to 14 the resolver would receive a finished report when the switchMap and the CustomPollOperator had finished it's job.

However, after updating the Angular version, the resolver does not wait for the polling to finish, and loads the page immediately after the first request that kicks of the job.

Any ideas what is causing this problem? I use the same code elsewhere when there is not a resolver involved and it functions as it did before.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say from angular 9 to 14 do you mean via 10-13? It's not recommended to jump major versions. See https://update.angular.io/

Comment: @AndrewAllen - out of my control - decision was made to jump from 9-14. This is the only remaining issue :)

Comment: I have a guess that your resolver gets a value. Your observable appears to be returning poll results. This way resolvers thinks its data appeared. To fix it you need to filter out polling process from the resulting stream. You can confirm my guess by piping a `tap(console.log, console.error, () => console.info('finished'))` to the observable in the resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pollFor` will emit the first result of this line:

```js
switchMap(() => this.http.get<any>(url + data.id, this.getAuthOptions(true))),
```

which will cause the route to resolve.

If you want to stop that from happening you need to apply a filter. I would just exchange the `tap` for a `filter`, and return `true` when the polling is complete, and `false` otherwise. This will only emit the result once polling is complete.

```js
return interval(ms).pipe(
    tap(() => console.warn('polling', shouldPoll)),
    takeWhile(() => shouldPoll),
    switchMap(() =>
      this.http.get<any>(url + data.id, this.getAuthOptions(true))
    ),
    filter((res) => {
      if (condComp(res)) {
        shouldPoll = false;
        return true;
      } else if (condFail(res)) {
        shouldPoll = false;
        throw new Error('Polling worker job failed');
      }
      return false;
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

I'm not really sure why this would act differently in Angular 9, although I've never used a resolver in that version. Are you sure it used to be polling multiple times before resolving? Keep in mind `interval` does not emit immediately. The interval timing is also the initial delay.

Comment: Hi Chris - thanks for that. When I change the tap to filter, it now gives the following error about the type of "res":              error: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: any, index: number) => value is any, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<any, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(res: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => value is any'.
      Signature '(res: any): void' must be a type predicate.
I'm not sure why it is complaining as i have specified "any" in the http.get()

Comment: It's telling you the return type is `void`, meaning you're not returning a boolean within the filter predicate? Double check `return false` is outside both conditions. ie. nothing should be emitted when the poll has neither completed nor failed.

Comment: Hmmmm. The return type of the https request is definitely not void, as i use this code elsewhere. This exact same code with the tap works elsewhere, where a resolver is not involved. I'm new to this stuff, and confused why the filter would think it would be void, but the tap not?

Comment: The return type of the filter predicate should be a boolean. The predicate is the function you pass in as a parameter to `filter`. ie. `filter((res) => { // This function should return a boolean but it is not returning anything })`

Comment: @TomO'Brien maybe you missed the two lines I added within that function?

Comment: That has done the trick! My bad - i didn't see those lines... doh! Thanks Chris.